# prevent old thumbnails from resizing?

Tags: php, image

How do I prevent the posts subsequent from the first from resizing? Ideally, all images should be 590px wide regardless of post order.

[This is the live site.](http://dapculture.com/)

It seems to me that this bit of code would have something to do with it, but regardless of what I change the widths to, the problem persists.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );  
set_post_thumbnail_size( 590, 275, true ); // 590 pixels wide by 275 pixels tall, hard crop mode
add_image_size( 'following-post-thumbnails', 250, 200, true ); // 250 pixels wide by 200 pixels tall, hard crop mode
```

Full functions.php

```
<?php


if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width  = '590';


/**
* Add Menu Support
**/

add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');
register_nav_menu('main', 'Main Nav');

/**
* Add editor style - recommended according to Theme-Check
**/
add_editor_style('editor-style.css');


/**
* Add custom background with custom background colour fix 
* as shown here: http://devpress.com/blog/custom-background-fix-for-theme-developers/
**/

add_custom_background( 'grisaille_custom_background_callback' );

function grisaille_custom_background_callback() {

    /* Get the background image. */
    $image = get_background_image();

    /* If there's an image, just call the normal WordPress callback. We won't do anything here. */
    if ( !empty( $image ) ) {
        _custom_background_cb();
        return;
    }

    /* Get the background color. */
    $color = get_background_color();

    /* If no background color, return. */
    if ( empty( $color ) )
        return;

    /* Use 'background' instead of 'background-color'. */
    $style = "background: #{$color};";

?>
<style type="text/css">body { <?php echo trim( $style ); ?> }</style>
<?php

}

/**
* Add custom header
**/

define('HEADER_TEXTCOLOR', '334759');
define('HEADER_IMAGE', ''); // %s is the template dir uri
define('HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH', 960); // use width and height appropriate for your theme
define('HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT', 200);

// gets included in the site header

function grisaille_header_style() {

    ?><style type="text/css">
        #site-title {
            background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>) 0 0 no-repeat;
            min-height: <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>px;
            margin: 20px 0;          
        }
        #site-title h1 a {
            color:#<?php header_textcolor(); ?> ;
            min-height: <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>px;
        }
        #site-description {
            color:#<?php header_textcolor(); ?> ;
        }
        <?php if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() ) { ?>
        #site-title h1 {
            padding: 0;
        }
        #site-title h1 a  {
            display:block;
            text-indent:-99999px;
        }
        #site-description {
            display: none;
            text-indent:-99999px;
        }

<?php } ?>
</style>
<?php
}
// gets included in the admin header
function grisaille_admin_header_style() {
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
            font-family: 'WoodenNickelBlackRegular';
    src: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/type/WOODENNI-webfont.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/type/WOODENNI-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/type/WOODENNI-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/type/WOODENNI-webfont.svg#webfontDYhQeecV') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

        #headimg h1 {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        #headimg h1 a{
            font:80px WoodenNickelBlackRegular, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            padding-left: 30px;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            text-decoration:none;
            width: <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>px;
            height: <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>px;
        }
        #desc {
            font:26px  Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }
    </style><?php
}
add_custom_image_header('grisaille_header_style', 'grisaille_admin_header_style');

/**
* Change Excerpt length
**/
function grisaille_new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'grisaille_new_excerpt_length');

/**
* Change excerpt [...] to something else
**/

function grisaille_new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return ' ... <br /><a class="more-link" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . __('">keep reading</a>', 'grisaille');
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'grisaille_new_excerpt_more');

/**
* Thumbnail support
**/

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );  
set_post_thumbnail_size( 590, 275, true ); // 590 pixels wide by 275 pixels tall, hard crop mode
add_image_size( 'following-post-thumbnails', 250, 200, true ); // 250 pixels wide by 200 pixels tall, hard crop mode

// THIS LINKS THE THUMBNAIL TO THE POST PERMALINK
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'grisaille_post_image_html', 10, 3 );
function grisaille_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {

    $html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';

    return $html;
}

/**
* Google font API - adding Ubuntu font
**/
function grisaille_enqueue_scripts_styles() {
         wp_enqueue_style( 'Marvel', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marvel');                                                 
}     
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'grisaille_enqueue_scripts_styles'); 

/**
* checks if the visitor is browsing either a page or a post and adds the 
* JavaScript required for threaded comments if they are
**/
function grisaille_queue_js(){
  if (!is_admin()){
    if ( is_singular() AND comments_open() AND (get_option('thread_comments') == 1))
      wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
  }
}
add_action('get_header', 'grisaille_queue_js');

/**
* register_sidebar()
**/

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'grisaille_register_sidebars' );

function grisaille_register_sidebars() {

    /* Register the 'primary' sidebar. */
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'id' => 'grisaillesidebar',
            'name' => __( 'Grisaille Sidebar', 'grisaille' ),
            'description' => __( 'Main right sidebar.', 'grisaille' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebaritem">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>'
        )
    );

}   

/**
* Load the Theme Options Page for social media icons
*/
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/inc/theme-options.php' );


/**
* Loads the theme's translated strings
*/

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'grisaille_language_theme_setup');
function grisaille_language_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain('grisaille', get_template_directory() . '/lang');
}   
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

  get_header();

  if (have_posts()): ?>

  <ol id="posts">
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


      <h2 class="postTitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
       <span class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1 ', '%'); ?></span>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
       <p class="theDate"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></a> <?php _e('by', 'grisaille'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?></p>

      <div class="post-wrap">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('following-post-thumbnails'); ?>
      <?php the_excerpt(__('keep reading', 'grisaille')); ?></div>
      <?php wp_link_pages(
                array(  'before'           => '<p class="pages-links">' . __('Pages:', 'grisaille'),
                        'after'            => '</p>',
                        'next_or_number'   => 'number',
                        'nextpagelink'     => __('Next page', 'grisaille'),
                        'previouspagelink' => __('Previous page', 'grisaille'),
                        'pagelink'         => '%')); ?>
      <p class="postMeta"><small><?php _e('Category', 'grisaille'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php _e('Tags', 'grisaille'); ?>: <?php the_tags(' '); ?></small></p>

      <hr class="noCss" />
    </li>

    <?php comments_template(); // Get wp-comments.php template ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </ol>

<?php else: ?>

  <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'grisaille'); ?></p>

  <?php endif; ?>


    <div class="pagination-older"><?php next_posts_link( __('&laquo; Older Entries', 'grisaille')); ?></div>
    <div class=" pagination-newer"><?php previous_posts_link( __('Newer Entries &raquo;', 'grisaille')); ?></div> 






  <?php
  get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: `grisaille_post_image_html()` doesn't appear to even use its second parameter...

Comment: Have you tried removing `add_image_size( 'following-post-thumbnails', 250, 200, true );`?

Comment: @Aaron yep, removed the function and the resize persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove this line, it is used for defining a custom thumbnail size:

```
add_image_size( 'following-post-thumbnails', 250, 200, true ); // 250 pixels wide by 200 pixels tall, hard crop mode
```

Then change the following line in index.php (it's telling the thumbnails to use the custom image size defined above):

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('following-post-thumbnails'); ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

That should result in your thumbnails using the default size specified on this line:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 590, 275, true );
```

I'm not sure how Wordpress' thumbnails work, but try uploading new images to see if the thumbnails get resized correctly. It looks like the subsequent posts' thumbnails are cropped permanently and would not resize by changing the code.

If that doesn't work, hopefully the documentation here should help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail